# So, what exactly is an 'ultra-cool' dwarf star?

Tags: star, terminology, dwarf-star, trappist-1

The [TRAPPIST-1 system](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/news/1419/nasa-telescope-reveals-largest-batch-of-earth-size-habitable-zone-planets-around-single-star/) is around an ultra-cool dwarf star. I went looking for more information on that kind of star, and found very little. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-cool_dwarf) on it lengthened from a minimal stub to one paragraph in the 15 minutes from when I began the search, after the press conference on the discovery of 7 Earth-sized planets in orbit around TRAPPIST-1.

What kind of star is this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Breaking the phrase down:

- [*Dwarf star*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_star) - a term I will never understand - is used to describe relatively small, dim stars. Unfortunately, this encompasses most main-sequence stars, which are indeed dwarfs compared to large giants and supergiants.
- *Ultra-cool*, as [called2voyage](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20128/2153) already discussed, [means that](http://www.eso.org/public/archives/releases/sciencepapers/eso1615/eso1615a.pdf) the star has an

  > effective temperatures of less than 2,700 kelvin.

  This is about half of the Sun's surface temperature. Spectroscopically, it means that these stars are of class [M7-L8](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/510132/meta), i.e. really, really cool stars that just barely reach the threshold for nuclear fusion. Actually, some L dwarfs will never fuse hydrogen as normal stars do, and will become brown dwarfs. Therefore, "ultra-cool dwarf" doesn't necessarily refer to just main sequence stars.

Other characteristics in some cases (from [Cruz et al](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/510132/meta).):

- Lithium in some L-type objects, indicative of low temperatures, low masses, and young ages in those particular objects.
- Very low surface gravities in late M-type dwarfs (though likely not as much in an M7 dwarf like TRAPPIST-1).
- Very low metallicity in certain other L-type objects.

TRAPPIST-1 actually appears to be a rather massive ultra-cool dwarf, then, in comparison to some of these other objects.

Here's an annotated Hertzsprung-Russell diagram, with a box for ultra-cool dwarfs and a circle for where TRAPPIST-1 is, approximately:

[image]

<sup>Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HRDiagram.png) courtesy of user Saibo, under [the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 2.5 Generic license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/deed.en).</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54135/discussion-on-answer-by-hde-226868-so-what-exactly-is-an-ultra-cool-dwarf-sta).

Comment: Funny detail: Our sun is also considered to be a dwarf star.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Spectroscopic Properties of Ultra-cool Dwarfs and Brown Dwarf](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1998ASPC..134..405K) by J.D. Kirkpatrick, the working definition of ultra-cool dwarf is:

> dwarfs having classifications of M7 or later.

That is referring to the [stellar classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification) system which categorizes stars by their spectral characteristics. Class M stars have a surface temperature less than 4000 K, and "M7 or later" means surface temperature less than 2500 K. Though it should be noted that this is a working definition, and the Wikipedia article identifies ultra-cool dwarfs as objects with surface temperature less than 2700 K. It is possible that the term is still used somewhat loosely in scientific papers.